# Заблокировать скролл body при скролле модального окна JS

Tags: html, css

Есть некая кнопка, при нажатии на которую появляется `div` блок с `position: fixed;` и закрывает весь экран.

В этом `div` есть контент и он не помещается на весь экран.

Добавляю стиль `overflow: scroll` для прокрутки.

Все работает, но справа два скролла: один для всей страницы, который можно крутить, но ничего не будет происходить, так как на весь экран у меня фиксированный блок, а второй для данного блока.

Как можно избавиться от первого скролла для всей страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно решить с помощью добавления класса `.fixed` к "обертки" с контентом в момент когда модальное окно отрыто:

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Данный вариант один из самый универсальных и будет одикого хорошо работать как на desctop'aх так и на мобильных устройствах.

Однако, есть один нюанс:

После закрытия модального окна контент будет находиться в самом начале страницы (т.е просколлен в самый верх).

Решается с помощью программного управлением скроллом в момент закрытия модального окна, для чего нужно запомнить положения скролла при открытии и восстановить его при закрытии.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  document.querySelector(".modal").classList.toggle("hide")
  document.querySelector(".content").classList.toggle("fixed")
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">Основной контент<br><br><br><br>Есть много вариантов Lorem Ipsum, но большинство из них имеет не всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки или слова, которые даже отдалённо не напоминают латынь. Если вам нужен Lorem Ipsum для серьёзного проекта, вы наверняка не хотите какой-нибудь шутки, скрытой в середине абзаца. Также все другие известные генераторы Lorem Ipsum используют один и тот же текст, который они просто повторяют, пока не достигнут нужный объём. Это делает предлагаемый здесь генератор единственным настоящим Lorem Ipsum генератором. Он использует словарь из более чем 200 латинских слов, а также набор моделей предложений. В результате сгенерированный Lorem Ipsum выглядит правдоподобно, не имеет повторяющихся абзацей или "невозможных" слов.Есть много вариантов Lorem Ipsum, но большинство из них имеет не всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки или слова, которые даже отдалённо не напоминают латынь. Если вам нужен Lorem Ipsum для серьёзного проекта, вы наверняка не хотите какой-нибудь шутки, скрытой в середине абзаца. Также все другие известные генераторы Lorem Ipsum используют один и тот же текст, который они просто повторяют, пока не достигнут нужный объём. Это делает предлагаемый здесь генератор единственным настоящим Lorem Ipsum генератором. Он использует словарь из более чем 200 латинских слов, а также набор моделей предложений. В результате сгенерированный Lorem Ipsum выглядит правдоподобно, не имеет повторяющихся абзацей или "невозможных" слов.Есть много вариантов Lorem Ipsum, но большинство из них имеет не всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки или слова, которые даже отдалённо не напоминают латынь. Если вам нужен Lorem Ipsum для серьёзного проекта, вы наверняка не хотите какой-нибудь шутки, скрытой в середине абзаца. Также все другие известные генераторы Lorem Ipsum используют один и тот же текст, который они просто повторяют, пока не достигнут нужный объём. Это делает предлагаемый здесь генератор единственным настоящим Lorem Ipsum генератором. Он использует словарь из более чем 200 латинских слов, а также набор моделей предложений. В результате сгенерированный Lorem Ipsum выглядит правдоподобно, не имеет повторяющихся абзацей или "невозможных" слов.Есть много вариантов Lorem Ipsum, но большинство из них имеет не всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки или слова, которые даже отдалённо не напоминают латынь. Если вам нужен Lorem Ipsum для серьёзного проекта, вы наверняка не хотите какой-нибудь шутки, скрытой в середине абзаца. Также все другие известные генераторы Lorem Ipsum используют один и тот же текст, который они просто повторяют, пока не достигнут нужный объём. Это делает предлагаемый здесь генератор единственным настоящим Lorem Ipsum генератором. Он использует словарь из более чем 200 латинских слов, а также набор моделей предложений. В результате сгенерированный Lorem Ipsum выглядит правдоподобно, не имеет повторяющихся абзацей или "невозможных" слов.Есть много вариантов Lorem Ipsum, но большинство из них имеет не всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки или слова, которые даже отдалённо не напоминают латынь. Если вам нужен Lorem Ipsum для серьёзного проекта, вы наверняка не хотите какой-нибудь шутки, скрытой в середине абзаца. Также все другие известные генераторы Lorem Ipsum используют один и тот же текст, который они просто повторяют, пока не достигнут нужный объём. Это делает предлагаемый здесь генератор единственным настоящим Lorem Ipsum генератором. Он использует словарь из более чем 200 латинских слов, а также набор моделей предложений. В результате сгенерированный Lorem Ipsum выглядит правдоподобно, не имеет повторяющихся абзацей или "невозможных" слов.</div>
  <button>Открыть / Закрыть</button>
  <div class="modal hide">Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32. Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32.Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -2):

При открытии `div` блока можно добавлять

```js
// js
document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
// jquery
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Comment: @ Sergey Mironov `overflow: hidden;` сам по себе не будет работать на мобильных устройствах, таких как iOS